# C# - Zip same Directory twice - different hash values

Tags: c#, hash, zip, archive

Im zipping the exact same files but the hash compare (tried MD5 and SHA256) is different. I read that its not possible to compare zip files because they somehow are always different after being zipped again with the same files.
What can I do instead do create same archives?

Zipping

```
        private string CreateZip(string path)
    {
        var targetPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\" +
                         RandomString() + ".zip";
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, targetPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
        return targetPath;
    }
```

Hashing

```
        static string CalculateMD5(string filename)
    {
        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
            {
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*I read that its not possible to compare zip files because they somehow are always different*" - where did you read this? I am only guessing here, more than likely the issue is if one tiny thing changes, last accessed time stamp ect, then they will not have the same hash

Comment: No, im zipping them immediately twice, no application even touches the files. Im sure its because of the zip compression.

Comment: You are touching them, getting a handle to the file, opening them with the win32 api, which likely smashes the time stamp... once again, just a guess

Comment: reading not writing, so the timestamp could be it?

Comment: The Last Access Time stamp displays an updated time each file and folder on a NTFS volume was last accessed. Once again, just a guess, but more than likely. If this is the problem, then you could set that last accessed time to something like unix epoch or the birthday of your dog or something, it might work

Comment: Before zipping them I added the following code and sadly it didnt work:                     var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                File.SetLastAccessTime(file, new DateTime(2020, 02, 1));
            }

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Using the same `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` call as you I created multiple archives from the same source and the hash is always the same. Are you sure that no files in the source directory are changing? I would suggest verifying the hash of each file in the archive against the corresponding file in the second archive.

Comment: Still...     ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(path, targetPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
            File.SetLastAccessTime(targetPath, new DateTime(2020, 02, 1));
            File.SetCreationTime(targetPath, new DateTime(2020, 02, 1));
            File.SetLastWriteTime(targetPath, new DateTime(2020, 02, 1));

Comment: @Reticulated Spline: I made a small test, if only 1 file without files in sub dirs is hashed it works. Now if the the dir has subdirs with subfiles, the hash is different.

Comment: In my test I specified a directory which had subdirectories and files in those subdirectories and I get consistent results. Did you check the hashes of all the files in the archives? Maybe there is a hidden file that's changing?

Comment: I have no idea, i just compared all files of both extracted zip files. The content is exact the same. I used this tool to compare the folders http://checksumcompare.sanktuaire.com/home

Comment: or using this powershell script https://gist.github.com/cchamberlain/883959151aa1162e73f1 all files the same...

Comment: Quite possibly the answer is here: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/barriers-to-deterministic-reproducible-zip-files. See the paragraph about the "extended timestamp" field.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

Its the compression.

Instead of using:

```
CompressionLevel.Optimal
```

This one works (same hash values):

```
CompressionLevel.NoCompression
```

Comment: But do you have any idea why the zip compression would differ?

Answer (score 0):

Zipping a file is non-deterministic. Bit awkward property of creating a zip file.

Comment: Do you have any references for this claim or more details?